# Ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).arcticmodal is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Второй день не могу разобраться. На сайте в начале body подключена библиотека `arcticmodal-0.3.min.js`.

Там же есть попап, который вызывается раз в сутки для одного пользователя, и он работает. Вот его код:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя
    // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем
    if (!$.cookie('was')) {

      // Покажем всплывающее окно
      $('#boxUserFirstInfo').arcticmodal({
        closeOnOverlayClick: true,
        closeOnEsc: true
      });
    }

    // Запомним в куках, что посетитель к нам уже заходил
    $.cookie('was', true, {
      expires: 1,
      path: '/'
    });

  })
})(jQuery)
```

Но я пытаюсь сделать ещё несколько попапов открывающихся по клику и вешаю на элемент:

```
onclick="$('.pop-b').arcticmodal();"
```

На самом деле - попапов с классом .pop-b у меня много. Вот код:

```
<ul class="on_ul">
  <li onclick="$('.pop-b').arcticmodal();"><span>Сбор информации и Анализ существующей ситуации с отходами, подготовка концептуального предложения и разработка дорожной карты</span>
  </li>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="box-modal pop-b" id="boxUserFirstInfo1">
      <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close"></div>
      <h3><span class="green">ПОСЛЕДНИЕ Н<span class="line">ОВОС</span>ТИ</span> КОМПАНИИ</h3>
      <div class="popup-news-h">
        У России появится новый орган – мусорный.</div>
      <p>
        В МИНПРОМТОРГЕ разрабатывают долгосрочную Стратегию развития промышленности по переработке и утилизации отходов до 2030 года. Газета «Ведомости» приводит сегодня обзор основных положений этого документа. Основными сдерживающими факторами создания индустрии
        отходов эксперты называют отсутствие раздельного сбора</p>
      <a href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/u-rossii-poyavitsya-novyj-organ-musornyj/" class="popup-permalink" target="_blank">читать дальше &gt;</a>

      <div><a target="_blank" href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/category/novosti/" class="all-news">ВСЕ НОВОСТИ</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <li onclick="$('.pop-b').arcticmodal();"><span>Проведение исследований морфологического состава отходов</span>
  </li>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="box-modal pop-b" id="boxUserFirstInfo1">
      <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close"></div>
      <h3><span class="green">ПОСЛЕДНИЕ Н<span class="line">ОВОС</span>ТИ</span> КОМПАНИИ</h3>
      <div class="popup-news-h">
        У России появится новый орган – мусорный.</div>
      <p>
        В МИНПРОМТОРГЕ разрабатывают долгосрочную Стратегию развития промышленности по переработке и утилизации отходов до 2030 года. Газета «Ведомости» приводит сегодня обзор основных положений этого документа. Основными сдерживающими факторами создания индустрии
        отходов эксперты называют отсутствие раздельного сбора</p>
      <a href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/u-rossii-poyavitsya-novyj-organ-musornyj/" class="popup-permalink" target="_blank">читать дальше &gt;</a>

      <div><a target="_blank" href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/category/novosti/" class="all-news">ВСЕ НОВОСТИ</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <li onclick="$('.pop-b').arcticmodal();"><span>Определение нормативов накопления отходов</span>
  </li>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="box-modal pop-b" id="boxUserFirstInfo1">
      <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close"></div>
      <h3><span class="green">ПОСЛЕДНИЕ Н<span class="line">ОВОС</span>ТИ</span> КОМПАНИИ</h3>
      <div class="popup-news-h">
        У России появится новый орган – мусорный.</div>
      <p>
        В МИНПРОМТОРГЕ разрабатывают долгосрочную Стратегию развития промышленности по переработке и утилизации отходов до 2030 года. Газета «Ведомости» приводит сегодня обзор основных положений этого документа. Основными сдерживающими факторами создания индустрии
        отходов эксперты называют отсутствие раздельного сбора</p>
      <a href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/u-rossii-poyavitsya-novyj-organ-musornyj/" class="popup-permalink" target="_blank">читать дальше &gt;</a>

      <div><a target="_blank" href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/category/novosti/" class="all-news">ВСЕ НОВОСТИ</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <li onclick="$('.pop-b').arcticmodal();"><span>Разработка бизнес-планов</span>
  </li>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="box-modal pop-b" id="boxUserFirstInfo1">
      <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close"></div>
      <h3><span class="green">ПОСЛЕДНИЕ Н<span class="line">ОВОС</span>ТИ</span> КОМПАНИИ</h3>
      <div class="popup-news-h">
        У России появится новый орган – мусорный.</div>
      <p>
        В МИНПРОМТОРГЕ разрабатывают долгосрочную Стратегию развития промышленности по переработке и утилизации отходов до 2030 года. Газета «Ведомости» приводит сегодня обзор основных положений этого документа. Основными сдерживающими факторами создания индустрии
        отходов эксперты называют отсутствие раздельного сбора</p>
      <a href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/u-rossii-poyavitsya-novyj-organ-musornyj/" class="popup-permalink" target="_blank">читать дальше &gt;</a>

      <div><a target="_blank" href="http://www.eco-t-m.ru/category/novosti/" class="all-news">ВСЕ НОВОСТИ</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Т.е. при клике на li должен открываться следующий за ним попап и я понимаю, что селлекторы надо переписывать но суть в том, что по клику сейчас не открывает вообще ничего.

При нажатии на него в консоль выкидывает ошибку, что в заголовке темы.

Вот сайт на котором наблюдается проблема https://web.archive.org/web/20161001153145/http://www.eco-t-m.ru/

Comment: "Вот сайт на котором наблюдается проблема" вы хоть напишите что нажать, чтобы увидеть проблему.

Comment: в блоке "ПРЕДПРОЕКТНЫЙ БЛОК" нужно нажать "узнать подробнее" - там выпадет список и при клике по пункту списка должен выскакивать попап

Comment: На момент выполнения кода для отображения всплывающего окна (для нового посетителя) функция `$.fn.arcticmodal` существует. Когда страница прогружается до конца - функция пропадает. Вы где-то ее затираете, либо перезагружаете jQuery заново. **З.Ы.** Главная страница весит **30 МЕГАБАЙТ** - это просто не реальное значение, если учесть что функциональности вообще никакой. На скорости 3 мегабит/с страница грузится целую **минуту**.

Comment: Функция вроде не должна нигде затираться. Подключен только arcticmodal с оф. сайта и кусок кода, что я кинул выше, относящийся к нему. А где может перезагружаться jQuery?

Comment: Я не смог найти проблемное место, т.к. на сайте много скриптов, к тому же сжатых. Берите исходники и ищите проблему, отключая скрипты и проверяя потерю функции.

Comment: Какой-то трэш. Название сайта содержит слово "эко" (экологично?) новости про минпром в вопросе, а сайт сплошной дейтинг и секс чаты. Предполагается, что участник за 500 репутации предлагает подебажить его сайт (минимальный пример не просматривается в вопросе) или пиарит сайт сомнительного содержания?

Comment: Не знаю. 4 года назад все воспроизводилось

Comment: а разве эта конструкция `$('.pop-b')` не должна вернуть массив? Если так - то, конечно, у массива нет метода `arcticmodal`

Comment: @Дмытрык если перенести это в ответ то можно получить +500

Comment: @Дмытрык, она возвращает объект jQuery

Comment: @AK, так как текущий сайт не соответствует вопросу, а без него ответить на вопрос _почему не работает_ невозможно предлагаю отменить конкурс и закрыть вопрос как не воспроизводится

Comment: @Grundy я категорически против. Есть вебархив

Comment: @РашенБеар, тогда отредактируй ссылку в вопросе.

Comment: Мне лень. Пусть ее отредактирует кто-то из проголосовавших за этот вопрос (видимо он показался им хорошим)

Answer (score 0):

У JQ есть функция next, если див стоит за LI то можно обратиться к нему следующей конструкцией

```
$('.on_ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).next().find('.pop-b').first().arcticmodal();
});
```